# Sharding Crashing On Shard 0 Discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sharding

I am trying to shard my discord bot in v13, and when I run just the main file (bot.js) on my beta bot without sharding, it works fine, but when I try running it with sharding, It gives this error.

[image]

Here is the index.js code where I shard

```js
const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js');

const manager = new ShardingManager('./bot.js', { token: 'tokenhere' });

manager.on('shardCreate', shard => console.log(`Launched shard ${shard.id}`));

manager.spawn();
```

When I try running just bot.js without sharding, it gives the error that says too many guilds on one session, meaning the main file is fine.

Here is the main file code

https://pastebin.com/8JNFxXqY

I don't think there are any errors on this file. Please let me know how to fix this, and how to shard properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `node .` which if I am not mistaken starts all the .js files in the folder you are in.

What happens is that both `index.js` and `bot.js` files are started.

You must run ONLY the file where the **ShardingManager** is, with `node index.js`.

Comment: Tested this theory. Seems like that might not be the case as `node .` only ran `test.js` in my testing: https://i.ibb.co/PjmPP6h/image.png

Comment: @CoderTavi Well, I use `node .` frequently because it runs all the `.js` files in the path I'm in (so I can run multiple files in what I think is a single process)

Note that I always require these files in the index.js to avoid errors when executing with `node .`

Comment: I used node . and it still only ran one file (tested it) I will give you the bounty since it is gonna expire. Thanks for your time!